# I'm receiving this error when trying to run my application using the npm start command

Tags: javascript

```
> npm start  
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-06T16_20_11_109Z-debug-0.log
```

I want to run Parcel.

Comment: So did you check to see whether there's actually such a script? Run the command it suggests, or _looked_? What are you asking us for?

Answer (score 0):

when you type `npm <script>` this will only take script names which are defined in your package.json. Make sure you have defined start inside `scripts` object like this

```
{
.
.
.
 "scripts": {
  .
  .
  .
  "start": "<some command>",
  .
  .
  .
 }
}
```

The error that you are getting is straightforward as it says missing scripts.

if you are using parcel then you must have package.json something like this.

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "latest"
  }
}
```